# Enable editable Google Doc inside an iframe

Tags: reactjs, nginx, iframe, google-api, google-docs

I have tried to add an iframe of google doc inside my application (react). The iframe works - I can see the doc, and edit it. but I keep getting these errors:

[image]

I have added the `X-Frame-Option` header to my Nginx with "SAMEORIGIN" always attribute without success. (didn't work)

Also added some sandbox configuration to the iframe itself so it can't redirect.

The HTML file head:
[HTML head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNaDT.png)

Please let me know if you have more ideas.

Comment: Can you please share your html?

Comment: Sure, editing the original post

Comment: did you find a solution? @matanyemini

Comment: Nope:( I was just manage to run stuff, but I always get these errors